# calling to a web service from startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges didUpdateLocations: callback

Tags: ios, objective-c, callback, location

I created a small application based on ibeacons and location.

I am calling a web service to download some information.

When I call the function "downloadDataFromServerWithMajor" from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions its works ok.

The problem comes when the app is on background and the "startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges" calls "didUpdateLocations" callback. The "fetchNetworkFromMajor" from Manager.m is firing, and i get the two logs:

```
NSLog(@"fetchNetworkFromMajor -->PATH:%@", path);
    NSLog(@"fetchNetworkFromMajor -->major:%@  -->version:%ld -->language:%@", major, (long)version, language);
```

but since then nothing happens, no response object or error on get function.

```
[self GET:path parameters:nil
      success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
          NSMutableArray *networks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[responseObject count]];
          NSLog(@"responseObject: %@", responseObject );
                       Network *net = [[Network alloc] initWithJSONDictionary:responseObject];
              if (net) {
                  NSLog(@"NET:%@", net);
                  [networks addObject:net];
              }

          successHandler(networks);
      }
      failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
          NSLog(@"error  manager:%@", error);
          errorHandler(error);
      }];
```

My code (from AppDelegate.m and Manager.m) is below:

AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation AppDelegate

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

        [self downloadDataFromServerWithMajor:@"1" andVersion:1];

        if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey]) {
            id locationValue = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey];

            [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

            NSString *message =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey %@",locationValue];
            [self sendLocalNotificationWithMessage:message];
        }
        if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
            NSLog(@"RESPONDS!!!!!");
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeSound|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge categories:nil]];
        }

        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        NSUUID *beaconUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6A"];
        NSString *regionIdentifier = @"iBeacons region 1";
        CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID: beaconUUID identifier: regionIdentifier ];
        beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];

        if([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]){
            [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        }

        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion];
        return YES;
    }

    - (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region{

       if(beacons.count > 0){
        for (CLBeacon *beacon in beacons){
                NSLog(@"beacon detectado major: %@ minor: %@", beacon.major,beacon.minor);

        }
       }
    }



    - (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region{
        [manager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*) region];
        NSLog(@"didEnterRegion --> has entrado en la region");
    }

    - (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region{
        [manager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*) region];
        NSLog(@"didExitRegion  --> has salido de la region");
    }

    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region{
        if (state == CLRegionStateInside) {
            //Start Ranging
            [manager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*) region];
            NSLog(@"didDetermineState -->has entrado en la region");
        }else{
            //Stop Ranging
            [manager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*) region];
        }
    }


    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
        //[self detectBluetooth];
        NSString *message = @"didUpdateLocations";
        [self sendLocalNotificationWithMessage:message];
        [self downloadDataFromServerWithMajor:@"1" andVersion:1];

    }

    -(void)sendLocalNotificationWithMessage:(NSString*)message {
       UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        notification.alertBody = message;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

    }



    - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
        NSString *message =@"applicationDidEnterBackground";
        [self sendLocalNotificationWithMessage:message];
        [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }


    - (void) downloadDataFromServerWithMajor: (NSString *) major andVersion: (NSInteger) version
    {
        //downloadDataFromServer
        NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"downloadDataFromServerWithMajor -->major: %@ -->version:%ld", major,(long)version);
        [[MyFacade sharedInstance] fetchNetworkFromMajor:  major andVersion: version andLanguage: language withDelegate:self  errorHandler:self];
    }

    -(void)didEndFetchingNetwork:(NSArray *)network{
         NSLog(@"didEndFetchingNetwork");
    }

    -(void)networkFetchingEror:(NSError *)error
    {
        NSLog(@"error networkFetchingEror");
    }

    - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
        NSString *message =@"applicationDidBecomeActive";
        [self sendLocalNotificationWithMessage:message];
     // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    @end
```

Manager.m

```
-(void)fetchNetworkFromMajor:(NSString *)major andVersion:(NSInteger )version andLanguage: (NSString *) language
                  successHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *pois))successHandler
                  errorHandler:(void (^)(NSError *error))errorHandler {
       NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:ManagerFetchNetworkRelativeURLFormat,
                      major,(long)version, language];
    NSLog(@"fetchNetworkFromMajor -->PATH:%@", path);
    NSLog(@"fetchNetworkFromMajor -->major:%@  -->version:%ld -->language:%@", major, (long)version, language);

   [self GET:path parameters:nil
      success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
          NSMutableArray *networks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[responseObject count]];
          NSLog(@"responseObject: %@", responseObject );
                       Network *net = [[Network alloc] initWithJSONDictionary:responseObject];
              if (net) {
                  NSLog(@"NET:%@", net);
                  [networks addObject:net];
              }

          successHandler(networks);
      }
      failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
          NSLog(@"error  manager:%@", error);
          errorHandler(error);
      }];
}
```

I dont understand why the same call works correctly when run from "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" and when run from "didUpdateLocations" nothing happens.
Any ideas? I'm really frustrated with this issue.

add initialization of Manager

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static MyManager *_sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

        // Network activity indicator manager setup
        [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] setEnabled:YES];

        // Session configuration setup
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        sessionConfiguration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{
                                                       @"User-Agent"    : @"iOS Client"
                                                       };

        NSURLCache *cache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:10 * 1024 * 1024     // 10MB. memory cache
                                                          diskCapacity:50 * 1024 * 1024     // 50MB. on disk cache
                                                              diskPath:nil];

        sessionConfiguration.URLCache = cache;
        sessionConfiguration.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy;

        //sessionConfiguration.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData;

        // Initialize the session
        _sharedInstance = [[MyManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:MyManagerBaseURL] sessionConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];
    });

    return _sharedInstance;
}
```

EDIT: I added the call  [self downloadDataFromServerWithMajor:@"1" andVersion:1]; to the method didRangeBeacons: and when the app detcts a ibeacon on background the call works ok too.

Comment: Can you post the GET method. Where are you setting up your NSURLSessionConfiguration for background downloads

Comment: Im using the default method of AFNetworking

Comment: I added the call [self downloadDataFromServerWithMajor:@"1" andVersion:1]; to the method didRangeBeacons: and when the app detcts a ibeacon on background the call works ok too. I cant undestand why when the method is called from didUpdateLocations: nothings happen.

Answer (score 0):

In order to download in the background your NSURLSessionConfiguration has to be initialized as a background session.

[Apple Documentation for background downloads](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLSessionConfiguration/backgroundSessionConfiguration:)

Try this instead in your Manager initialization

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:@"bgDownload"];
```

Comment: The issue continues, but  I discovered something curious. The second time that startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges fires didUpdateLocations: the get method continues and receipt the data from server.  And a new get petition is send.